# Faster to consolidate regexes in a hash of regexes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string that I want to map to an integer. Many strings can map to the same integer, so I'm using regexes to match strings that should map to the same integer.

Example:

```
str = "hello"

REGEXES.each do |key, val|
  if str =~ key
    print val
  end
end
```

where REGEXES is a hash that maps regex to integer.

**Which is better:**

```
REGEXES = [/hello/ => 2, /foo/ => 2, /bar/ => 3]
```

or

```
REGEXES = [/(hello|foo)/ => 2, /bar/ => 3]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "better" (From what standpoint).  And are those the real regexes, or are they more complicated than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Benchmark` is your friend:

```
require 'benchmark'

str = 'hello'
num = 1000000

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('individual keys:') do
    regexes = [/hello/ => 2, /foo/ => 2, /bar/ => 3]

    num.times do
      regexes.each {|key, val| str =~ key}
    end
  end

  x.report('combined keys:  ') do
    regexes = [/(hello|foo)/ => 2, /bar/ => 3]

    num.times do
      regexes.each {|key, val| str =~ key}
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------------
individual keys:   1.600000   0.010000   1.610000 (  1.780246)
combined keys:     1.610000   0.010000   1.620000 (  1.761067)
------------------------------------------- total: 3.230000sec

                       user     system      total        real
individual keys:   1.570000   0.000000   1.570000 (  1.589879)
combined keys:     1.590000   0.010000   1.600000 (  1.678724)
```

As you can see, in this case there's not much difference.

I'd suggest that you try it with your full hash of regexes/integers, and see if the difference is more significant. If there is, well, there's your answer. If there's not, you can probably feel free to use whichever makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with second version since it'll reduce loop cycles count. Still if there're too much values mapping to the same int, you can split them up in separate hash elements.